# Как изменить ширину столбца?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify

Извините за банальный вопрос , но помогите мне поменять ширину столбца (это Vuetify). В документации не нашёл.

```
<v-data-table
        :headers="someHeaders"
        :items="someItems"
        :items-per-page="7"
        class="table"
      >
```

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу такой вариант. Это если содержание таблицы однородно. Можно вычислять размеры по самой широкой и высокой и выстраивать другие.

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.v-data-table td{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
</style>
```

Либо можно сделать следующим образом

```
  headers: [
    {
    text: '№',
    align: 'start',
    width: "1%",
    },
    { text: 'Столбец1', value: 'dataFormat', width: "1%" },
    { text: 'Столбец2', value: 'desc', width: "1%"},
    { text: 'Столбец3', value: 'owner', width: "1%"},
  ],
```